# Eliminate default CSS on outline levels

Tags: html, css

The H outline levels have a default format. For accessibility reasons I need to use outline levels strictly for their outline function, not their style. How can I eliminate the CSS attributes of the outline levels so they won't override the div I'm putting them in?

```
<div align="center" class="certTitle">
    <h1>Request History</h1>
</div>
```

This code results in text that is too big, the wrong typeface, and increases the size of the div to accomodate the margins in the h1 style. It overrides my certTitle style.

Yes, I could use h6, but that doesn't answer the margin or typeface or other questions.

I also can't simply style the H element:

```
<div align="center" class="certTitle">
    <h1 class="certTitle">Request History</h1>
</div>
```

because the style has a box border, and this gives me nested boxes.

Comment: Have you tried using a CSS reset?

Comment: [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) is the best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS reset such as normalize.css at https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css

Answer (score 0):

Check out CSS reset that could help you.